# Scroll To error and success message after submitting a form using ScrollTo jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, error-handling, scrollto

So far I have this working properly for the error message only. However, I would like this to work for success message as well. This should happen when the submit button is pressed in the contact form. Click contact at the top right of the page to scroll to it.

You can test it [here](http://new.syntheticmedia.net).

Here is the jQuery I'm using for the error message:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".error:first").attr("id","errors");
    $("#errors").each(function (){
        $("html,body").animate({scrollTop:$('#errors').offset().top-175}, 1000);
    });
  });
```

Any way to modify it to work with scrolling to #success and #errors with the same offset().top-175 ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var pos = null;
     if($("#contact-form #errors.visible").length > 0)
        pos = $('#errors').offset().top;

     if($("#contact-form #success.visible").length > 0)
        pos = $('#success').offset().top;

     if(pos != null)
         $("html,body").animate({scrollTop:pos-175}, 1000);
  });
```

**And fix the fact that your script "js/contact_script.js" must be declared after JQuery lib**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it isn't working. Even after I declared "js/contact_script.js" after jQuery lib. The reason I put "js/contact_script.js" before is because the "error" message from the form wasn't displaying correctly.

Comment: I made a mistake in my answer ("#errors.visible" is correct and not "#errors .visible"). I have updated the code

Comment: As you are using JQuery in contact_script, you need to declare it after, else you get an error : $ is not defined. Check your console (F12)

Comment: Your fix worked! You win! Yes, I understand the console errors, however, like I said the error message doesn't parse correctly if I declare it after jQuery lib. Might have something to do with PHP. In my experience, code is weird like that sometimes especially when there is a lot going on in one page. As long as it works, and everything else works on the page I'm happy. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't award the bounty yet for another 22 hours, but you will get it.

Answer (score 3):

this solution make the same job for Contact Form 7 (popular form plugin for WordPress). I found this page during the search by Google of my problem, so I added the solution below to help others who ended also at this page.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );
        wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".wpcf7-response-output").offset().top - 100
                }, 500);
            }, 500);
            //console.log("Submited");
        }, false );
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution is related just to Contact Form 7, maybe it is off-topic, if yes, feel free to delete. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $elementToScrollTo;
    var $firstError = $(".error:first");
    if ($firstError.length > 0) {
        $firstError.attr("id", "errors");
        $elementToScrollTo = $firstError;
    }
    else {
        $elementToScrollTo = $("#success");
    }
    $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: $elementToScrollTo.offset().top - 175
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but your solution scrolls to the success message, but doesn't scroll to the error message after submit. The opposite of mine! I should have mentioned that I'm testing this in Safari desktop and mobile i.e. iPad, because Chrome and Firefox handle the errors differently.